# getting values of multiple select2 select boxes which are on one page

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have multiple select2 boxes on one page and I want to get access to the value selected for each one.

I have tried adding each select tag to one class, for example: "my-select2-boxes" like so:

```
<select class="my-select2-boxes">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
</select>

<select class="my-select2-boxes">
  <option value="superman">Superman</option>
  <option value="batman">Batman</option>
</select>
```

And then I try:

```
 $(".my-select2-boxes").select2("data")
```

But this only returns the data from the first select element i.e. the one with Volva and Saab. How can I get access to the data of all the select elements

Comment: try `var selData = new Array(); $(".my-select2-boxes").each(function(i){ selData.push($(this).select2('data')); });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only giving you one set of data, because, even though the selector gets multiple elements, it cannot "guess" you want the data return of ALL element objects. Thus you should make use of jQuery's [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), which will allow you to subjugate the data of EACH element as needed.

Such as:

```
$(function() {
    var selData = new Array();
    $(".my-select2-boxes").each(function(i) {
        //  I'm not familiar with this plugin, but by your use,
        //  I assume calling .select2('data') returns the value
        //  of some custom div made from the select box?
        selData.push($(this).select2('data'));
    });
    console.log(selData);
})
```

Anytime you use a multiple element possible selector in jQuery, you willg et a return object of all matching elements. The object contains "element objects" of each element. However, if you then call for something that would return a string, such as `.text()`, it will simply select the first element object and give you only what is found for THAT object. If you need a base return of multiple elements, then you need [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)